# Remove "Comments" title section from node template

Tags: 7, comments

in my node.tpl.php i have this line:

```
<?php echo render($content['comments']); ?>
```

It works, but before comments I have a <div> with the text "Comments". I think that it is the section titles. I don't want it. Is there a possibility to remove it before "render" or I need to hide it via css ?

M.

Comment: Can you provide more code from your template? It's much easier to answer if we can see the context... from this much info I'd say you'd be fine just removing the text and leaving the div in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it via css or you can change the tpl file:

Look for the *comment-wrapper.tpl.php* file in your theme. If it doe not exist there, you can copy it from the modules/comment folder into your theme folder. Edit the file and remove the line:

```
<h2 class="title"><?php print t('Comments'); ?></h2>
```